# Incomplete type in std::function

Tags: c++, include, std-function

I have a `Target` class similar to the following:

```
class Target
{
  std::function<void(A&,B&,C&)> Function;
}
```

Now, one of these parameter types(say A), has a `Target` member and tries to invoke its function:

```
class A
{
  Target target;
  void Foo(B& b, C& c)
  {
    target.Function(*this,b,c);
  }
}
```

Somewhere down the line, these two types appear in a header file. Given the circular dependency, there is a forward declaration and, unfortunately, an `error : pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed` error.

So the question is - what can I do about this?

Comment: Define `Foo` out of line? I think you need to show exactly how the circularity arises - and exactly what error you get and where.

Comment: "what can I do about this?" - About what?

Comment: @SChepurin how can I avoid the error generated?

Comment: @AlanStokes yep, that's a possibility, but one that I'd like to avoid if possible

Answer (score 1):

You have a [circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) problem. Declare `target` as a pointer in `class A` and appropriately allocate it in the constructor and deallocate it in the destructor of the class:

```
class A
{
  A() : target(new Target) {}
  ~A() { delete target; }
  Target *target;
  void Foo(B &b, C &c)
  {
    target->Function(*this, b, c);
  }
};
```

If your compiler supports C++11 use smart pointers instead:

```
class A
{
  A() : target(std::unique_ptr<Target>(new Target)) {}
  std::unique_ptr<Target> target;
  void Foo(B &b, C &c)
  {
    (*target).Function(*this, b, c);
  }
};
```